# CSV files: excel hiding zeros

Tags: excel, vba, csv, formatting

if I load a csv file into excel, value 123.320000 will become 123.32.

i need to view all contents as they are. any way to stop excel from hiding trailing zeros?

reading other posts, i found that doing something like this could work "=""123.3200000" but that would mean running regex on the file every time i want to view it.. since it comes in xxxx|###|xxx format and i have no control over the generation part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How exactly are you loading the CSV file?

If you import it as "Text" format then Excel will retain all formatting, including leading/trailing zeros.

In Excel 2010 you import from the "Data" tab and choose "From Text", find your CSV file then when prompted choose to format the data as "Text"

Comment: i open the .csv in excel 2008, than use "text to columns" function, "text qualifer" "none" .. column data format: "text"

Comment: it looks like "column data format" is on column level.. my files have lots of columns..

Comment: you say "i open the .csv in excel 2008" - I mean DON'T "open" it in Excel, "import" it. Open up excel with no document loaded, click on "Data" tab and click "Import from Text" then go through the wizard, making sure you specify to import as Text

Comment: i just answered you question "how exactly are you loading csv file". did not ignore your suggestion. thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that once the imported values are in the sheet, you want to treat them as numbers and not as text, i.e. you want to be able to sum, multiply, etc. Loading the values as text will prevent you from doing this -- until you convert the values back to numbers, in which case you will lose the trailing zeros, which brings you back to your initial conundrum.

Keeping in mind that there is no difference between the *values* 123.32 and 123.3200000, what you want is just to change the *display format* such that the full precision of your value is shown explicitly. You could do this in VBA like so:

```
strMyValue = "123.3200000"

strFormat = "#."
' Append a 0 to the format string for each figure after the decimal point.
For i = 1 To Len(strMyValue) - InStr(strMyValue, ".")
    strFormat = strFormat & "0"
Next i

With Range("A1")
    .Value = CDbl(strMyValue)
    .NumberFormat = strFormat
    'Value now shown with same precision as in strMyValue.
End With
```